# How Can I enforce TLS 1.2 when using nusoap?

Tags: php, soap, tls1.2, nusoap, eway

I am using nusoap to connect Eway legacy Api. Suddenly Eway enforce TLS 1.2 on their side. So I have set open ssl 1.0 and TLS 1.2 in my server.

From that server I am connecting Eway rapid api which is working fine. As both Legacy and Rapid api needs TLS 1.2 and rapid is working fine that means our server setup i ok. But this legacy api connection is not working.

I need to enforce TLS 1.2 by code when I am connecting Eway legacy API using nusoap.

Code Example -

```
<?php

$client = new nusoap_client("https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill.asmx");
$client->namespaces['man'] = 'http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill';
$headers = "<man:eWAYHeader><man:eWAYCustomerID>****</man:eWAYCustomerID><man:Username>****</man:Username><man:Password>****</man:Password></man:eWAYHeader>";
$client->setHeaders($headers);

$requestbody = array();
$soapactionUrl = 'http://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill/';
$requestbody['man:RebillCustomerID'] = $eway_rebill_customer_id;
$requestbody['man:RebillID'] = $eway_rebill_id;
$soapaction = 'QueryRebillEvent';
$client = $this->_creatEwayRebillRequestHeader();

$result = $client->call('man:'.$soapaction, $requestbody, '', $soapactionUrl.$soapaction,true);
$err_msg = $client->getError();
echo $err_msg;
?>
```

The error massage what I am getting is -

> wsdl error: Getting `https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill.asmx` - HTTP ERROR: Unsupported HTTP response status 403 Forbidden (soapclient->response has contents of the response)

**I am sure about my credentials, also eway support team also told me to enforce TLS 1.2 to solve the issue. But I don't know how to enforce TLS 1.2 in the nusoap library.**

Comment: @machavity -- This is not a duplicate issue.. I am facing issue in nusoap. And the old question and the solution is in soap

Comment: Hmm. Apparently it's not. Weird that the asker says NuSOAP and then uses PHP SOAP. Anyways, digging into this I found an apparent answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you can tell NuSOAP to use CURL. So modifying the setup slightly should do the trick

```
$client = new nusoap_client("https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/manageRebill.asmx");
$client->setUseCURL(true);
$client->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, '6'); // TLS 1.2
```

I don't have a way to test this, but I based it on [the NuSOAP class found in GitHub](https://github.com/deviservi/nusoap/blob/master/lib/nusoap.php). This works for CURL so it should work here.